# R randomForest: prediction values for non-terminals?

Tags: r, random-forest

There is a discrepancy between the documentation for R randomForest and the output of the getTree() method.

The [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf) states that the value of the prediction field in getTree() should be zero for non-terminal nodes:

> prediction: the prediction for the node; 0 if the node is not terminal

This is the case for the classification method, however in the regression method there are non zero continuous values:

```
> library(randomForest)
> 
> x  <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=10))
> y  <- rnorm(10)
> 
> model <- randomForest(x,y)
> getTree(model,k=1)
  left daughter right daughter split var split point status prediction
1             2              3         2  0.49239435     -3 -0.1212934
2             4              5         2  0.09046437     -3 -0.4871480
3             0              0         0  0.00000000     -1  1.3421250
4             6              7         2 -0.61841853     -3 -0.2501163
5             0              0         0  0.00000000     -1 -1.1982434
6             0              0         0  0.00000000     -1 -0.8738258
7             0              0         0  0.00000000     -1  0.9973027
```

**Are these prediction values for non-terminal nodes used for prediction? If not, what is their purpose?**

On separate but related note, the `status` field doesn't adhere to the documentation for the regression method either:

> status: status is the node terminal (-1) or not (1)

As noted before, the classification method seems to follow the docs exactly:

```
> y_bin <- as.factor(y>0)
> model <- randomForest(x,y_bin)
> getTree(model,k=1)
  left daughter right daughter split var split point status prediction
1             2              3         2  -0.6184185      1          0
2             0              0         0   0.0000000     -1          1
3             4              5         1  -0.3887568      1          0
4             0              0         0   0.0000000     -1          1
5             0              0         0   0.0000000     -1          2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've confirmed with a test case that the prediction for the randomForest regressor does not depend on the decision node values in the prediction field:

```
> x     <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=10))
> y     <- rnorm(10)
> 
> model <- randomForest(x,y,ntree=1)
> getTree(model,k=1)
  left daughter right daughter split var split point status prediction
1             2              3         2  -0.1314179     -3 -0.1901029
2             0              0         0   0.0000000     -1 -1.6884260
3             4              5         2   1.0801034     -3  0.1844779
4             0              0         0   0.0000000     -1 -0.0447021
5             0              0         0   0.0000000     -1  0.4136579
> 
> test <- data.frame(X1=1,X2=1)
> predict(model,test)
         1 
-0.0447021
```

We can confirm that -0.0447021 is the value from the leaf node by tracing the data point (1,1) down the tree where "right daughter" is the correct child node if the value from the data point is greater than the cutoff.